# Rails controllers for subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to have multiple subdomains (for employers of two different roles in my company) and some resources are shared between them. But the actions and views of each subdomain are different.

What would be the best practice for organizing the controller and the views (I don't think that putting a lot of ifs on the views is a good thing). Should I create different controllers for each subdomain (I think this wouldn't be dry)? Should I create a base controller for the resources and inherit from them on each subdomain? What would you guys suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Create a `current_subdomain` method in the application controller and use it like a devise `current_user`.  Check `current_subdomain` when you have logic that differs across subdomains.

```
def current_subdomain
  server_name = request.env["SERVER_NAME"])
  subdomain = server_name.split('.').first
end
```

Comment: This would fall into the `if` problem, wouldn't it?

Comment: Correct, I don't recommend separate controllers across subdomains if there will be significant code re-use. Without knowing more about the specifics of what you are trying to solve its difficult for me to know how much overlap there will be.

Comment: I have a resource that the salespeople in my company will be able to create and edit and the admin will be able to edit it and approve it or not. But the edit form I would like to be completely different. I know I can limit the edit params with strong parameters, but I never thought putting `if`s on the code was a good thing.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are each user type on a different subdomain?

Comment: I know I could use RBAC and do everything on the same app, but I wanted to differentiate everything so it looked like two different systems internally in the company.

Comment: Ok, how would the edit form be different? Appearance or fields?

Comment: More importantly fields. I have already adapted layout for different subdomains.

Comment: Ok, I would just check the subdomain and render different partials which contain the different forms.